# Hiding pointers with references

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Is it a good thing to hide pointers members with setters that use references?

```
class Foo
{
    Bar* m_ptr;
public :
    void setBar(Bar& bar){m_ptr = &bar;}
};
```

Or is it preferable to expose the true type of referenced object in the setter (And why) ?

```
void setBar(Bar* bar){m_ptr = bar;}
```

In fact, I'm using stl conteners that are not "reference friendly", so I have vectors of pointers as class members but I prefer to deal with methods that takes references. Is it a bad thing to do that?

**EDIT :**

Stored members are pointers, this example fits better my question :

```
class Foo
{
   std::vector<FooObserver *> m_observers; 
public :
```

Do you prefer this :

```
void addObserver(FooObserver* obs);
```

Or this :

```
void addObserver(FooObserver& obs);
```

?

In both cases pointers should never be NULL and I assume this is the responsibility of the callers objects.

Answer (score 5):

For me it comes down to the semantics of the type.  If the pointer is masking a member that is never intended to be `NULL` then absolutely use a reference in both the input and output positions.  If the value can legally be `NULL` though then using a pointer is the best approach

Comment: That is a simple and good rule but I forgot to mention (before edit) that stored member should never be NULL. I Also need the stored member not to be just references.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you want to achieve, both are perfectly reasonable.

The only difference* is that `void setBar(Bar* bar)` will accept null pointers while `void setBar(Bar& bar)` obviously won't.

It's up to you to choose which one you want to use depending on whether you want to allow null pointers or not.

(*) assuming the author of `Bar` did not provide a custom `operator&` (which is an awful idea anyway).

---

**Edit:** Since you don't want to allow null pointers to be stored, a reference is preferable. You say "*pointers should never be NULL and I assume this is the responsibility of the callers objects*" but with a reference you have the opportunity to enforce that at compile time and avoid altogether relying on the caller's good will, which is much better design.

Comment: Wait. If `setBar` takes a reference and I do `Bar *b = NULL; setBar(*b)`, and inside `setBar` you take `&bar` and store it in a vector, there is no problem. You are still receiving NULL. References does not prevent you from getting NULL.

Comment: Generally, they use a reference to show an **intention** that you are planning on not accepting NULLs. Other than that, the language doesn't prevent you from getting it.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Dereferencing a null pointer is Undefined Behaviour, thus not correct C++. Some (most/all) compilers may choose to allow just what you wrote out of an efficiency concern (otherwise they'd have to check at runtime every single dereference for correctness, way to bring your program to a crawl) but that doesn't make it legal.

Comment: @syam, I understand that it's undefined behavior. But there is no way for the compiler to check against it. So I was pointing out that the sentence _void setBar(Bar* bar) will accept null pointers while void setBar(Bar& bar) obviously won't._ is not entirely correct, since the reference version may still get a NULL reference. Better wording would be _while void setBar(Bar& bar) is not intended to accept them._

Comment: @syam, I see. I didn't know `&(*(Bar *)0)` would be undefined behavior. I had assumed that would be legally reduced to `(Bar *)0`

Comment: @Shahbaz: The thing is, **there is no such thing as a "null reference" in C++**, it simply doesn't exist. Sure, when you enter UB territory you can do and say pretty much anything (this is the whole definition of UB: *There Be Dragons*) but this is not C++ any more. Nothing even guarantees that `&(*(Bar*)0)` will yield 0, since UB is involved. For all that we know dereferencing a null pointer could well format your hard drive and this still would be perfectly correct C++ *as far as the standard goes*, do you want to cover that case too?

Comment: @Shahbaz: (cont'd) What I'm trying to get you to understand is, it is totally **irrelevant** to discuss what could happen if you go UB since literally anything could happen. As C++ programmers, **all we need be concerned with is the standard** (and not stepping out of it, ie. not going UB) and in that respect my statement is entirely correct. (sorry, I was "editing" my comments while you posted ;))

Comment: @Shahbaz: Ok, last comment here since this discussion is getting too long: a compiler *can* legally reduce `&(*ptr)` to `ptr` by the *as-if* rule if `ptr` is not null. But if `ptr` is null, the same *as-if* rule means that this reduction is UB. Since a compiler can hardly guess what will happen at runtime, it makes sense for the compiler to assume it will always be legal, and it is our job to ensure we don't go UB. But if we go UB anyway, we don't need to concern ourselves (and neither does the compiler) with what will happen so, ironically, the reduction is still valid even though it is UB.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As it muddles your lifetime control of the two objects consider this

```
void AdjustFoo(Foo& f)
{

     Bar B;
     f.setBar(B);
     //Crap f now contains a bad pointer to B after this function exists 
}
```

IF foo needs to own a B it should own a shared_ptr or a copy of B.

Comment: I think in general properties should be `value types`

Comment: @Laurent I agree but a pointer implies that you need to watch life cycle issues.  References make it too easy.

Comment: @DyP yes to its a bad idea.  There is no issues with a function that uses a refrece but does not participate in ownership.

Comment: @rerun Ok so you suggest that exposing the type of stored value would "warn" the user to be careful of what he is doing, no?

Comment: I know it's a bad idea, I was just confused because the OP has three questions, where the last one is formulated as the inversion of the first one.

Comment: @Laurent Yes pointers imply I need this object live for as long as I do.  That is by no mean assured.  Afther c++ 11 I would use a shared_ptr to communicate that explicitly.

Comment: @rerun "pointers imply I need this object live for as long as I do" => How so? Many APIs use pointers only because the parameter is optional, without any consideration to the object's lifetime. I agree with your shared_ptr remark concerning ownership, but when it comes to raw pointers or references only proper documentation can settle the matter of lifetime.

Comment: So changing the stored type to shared pointers should ensure lifetime handling but we still can provide interface with references? no?

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of convention but I prefer one containing this:

- If the called method keeps a pointer of the passed object, use a pointer argument **and clearly state lifetime requirements in the API documentation**.
- If the called method just peeks (and maybe pokes) into the passed object during method execution, use a reference.
- Accepting a reference says: I only accept valid objects.
- Accepting a pointer says: I also accept null pointers unless explicitly stated otherwise.

BTW, I am not a fan of just putting shared pointers everywhere. Lifetime gets out of control and ownership is obscured. Of course, there are still very valid uses for shared pointers but never use them only because you don't want to think about lifetime and ownership.